# Adding numpy arrays to numpy array in a for loop

Tags: numpy

I have tried to add numpy arrays (multiple of `numpy_array`) in a for loop to a list where each numpy array might have varies shapes like (but let us say each has (10, 64)). So each array has 64 columns and might have as many rows as possible. What I did was the following:

```
l_arr = numpy_array[indices, :]
list_arr.append(l_arr.tolist())
```

Then,

```
numpy_from_list= np.array(list_arr)
```

But this seems to add extra dimension. For example If I added 3 numpy arrays each of size (10, 64) to a list and then convert a list to a numpy. I would get `(3, 10, 64)`, but instead I want `(30, 64)`.

```
for i in range(3):
    l_arr = numpy_array[indices, :]
    list_arr.append(l_arr.tolist())
    numpy_from_list= np.array(list_arr)
```

Can you please help me with that?

Comment: try to use numpy's np.stack() function

Comment: @sehan2. Thank you, but I got same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
arrays = [np.random.randint(0,10,(10, 64)) for i in range(3)]
res = np.vstack(arrays)
```

Comment: While running the loop, how I can set a condition that size of stacked arrays should not exceed 30 for example? I did your code and it works, but it has issues as the list size of 3 has actual array sizes of 30 by 64. So I can not set a condition to stop the loop based on list size like `while len(list_numpy_arryas) <=30:`

Comment: I am adding arrays iteratively not in a single call as you did with `arrays` above.

Comment: your arrays have to have compatible dimensions to stack them

Comment: They are not compatible unfortunatley. One might have (10, 64) while another might have (3, 64), etc. So I first added them to a list and once I finish I stacked them as you did, but the issue is I want to stop once I added a total of (64, 64) from all arrays. Can you help me with that please?

Comment: look into 'list comprehensions' or use a for loop as you did above

Comment: What I did is
 `size = 0 
while size <=64: 
list.append(array) for i in range(len(list)): size+=list[i].shape[0]`. Do you think this is efficient approach ?